# how to pass collection list between aspx pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0

**i have tried this code,which is not working.**

```
Dim FilteredAgentsList As New List(Of Object)
FilteredAgentsList = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("FilteredAgentsList"), List(Of Object))
```

Tried to access a class type list in object type through session.

```
Shared FilteredAgentsList As New List(Of Agents)
Me.Session("FilteredAgentsList") = FilteredAgentsList
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is not working???? Was there an exception???

Comment: Not showing any error but just coming out of the function if i am giving break point.

Comment: Are you sure that it is stored correctly in Session? Can you show the code where you store it?

Comment: @Koen above is my code where i stored the session variable

Comment: Does this happen on the same page too? Please, try for debugging reasons to reproduce it on the same page. Put the object in the session and retrieve it right after. Ensure that the object you store is not null, by using the immediate window or the debugger. Then share the results with us...

Comment: i did it on same page,it is showing error that:System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[InternationalWebReference.Agents]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why casting is necessary. Since you consider this necessary, you could use [ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. You could see the example on the link posted.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks to all.Direct assignment is not working. thats why i am converting

Comment: You should mark the correct answer (or at least give some credit) so that when another colleague finds the question, could also see the answer easily. Glad to help.

Comment: .Thanks a lot for the help,but sorry to say non of the above answer solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Why casting to `object`?
Try it like this:

```
Dim FilteredAgentsList As New List(Of Agents)
FilteredAgentsList = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("FilteredAgentsList"), List(Of Agents))
```

Comment: Because i need to get lists of different classes from different pages that is why i am using object type which can accept all type lists.@koen